# wildfly 10.1 mysql replication second database is read-only exception

Tags: mysql, jboss, regression, wildfly, wildfly-10

I started using Wildfly 10.1 and use mysql as a database. I have two databases, DB1 and DB2. Wildfly will connect to DB2 when D1 disconnected. I've done it so far. But when I connect to DB2, I get a "Connection is read-only" error. I looked at the topic here [Database Fail Over in Jboss Data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409111/database-fail-over-in-jboss-data-sources) but

```
> <connection-property name = "readOnly"> false </ connection-property>
```

not resolve. I'm looking for a solution to that. I want master/master not master/slave. In my mysql configuration in standalone.xml:

```
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/RailbaseLabDS" pool-name="RailbaseLabDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://IP1:3306,IP2:3306/DBN?autoreconnect=true</connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>
            <security>
                <user-name>DBN</user-name>
                <password>DBN</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                <background-validation-millis>5000</background-validation-millis>
            </validation>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
```

Comment: I need emergency help, isn't there anyone who can help?

Comment: I found the solution at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22145998/8945079). It make the second server access as read/write instead of read-only.